# AppStore Review Rejecting Subscription Because They Aren't Selecting the StoreKit Configuration

Tags: swiftui, in-app-purchase, configuration-files, storekit

I've been working with the AppStore Review process for several iterations, and their most recent message to me was this:

"We noticed that your app did not meet all the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement.

We were unable to find the following required information in your app's binary:

– Title of publication or service
– Length of subscription (time period and content or services provided during each subscription period)
– Price of subscription, and price per unit if appropriate
– A functional link to the Terms of Use (EULA)."

My problem is that all this information is included in my SwiftUI App code, like so:

> ```
> ForEach(storeVM.subscriptions) { product in
>     Button(action: {
>         Task {
>             await buy(product: product)
>             flashes.SubPop = false
>         }
>     })
>     label: {
>         VStack {
>             VStack {
>                 Text("Try 7 Days for Free!")
>                     .fontWeight(.bold)
>                     .foregroundColor(.mint)
>                 HStack {
>                      Text("Then " + product.displayPrice + "/Month")
>                 }
>             }
>             .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.7, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.07)
>             .overlay(
>                 RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
>                     .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 4)
>                     .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.7, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.07))
>                     .padding()
>                        
>               Link(destination: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/dev/stdeula/")!, label: {
>                   HStack {
>                       Text("Terms of Use")
>                           .foregroundColor(.mint)
>                   }
>     })
> }
> ```

When I run my App in XCode, the button I described above will not appear on the screen unless I *edit the scheme and select my StoreKit configuration*. If I select my StoreKit configuration, then all the information appears just as it's supposed to.

The AppStore review people have sent me a screenshot of their problem, and it's basically what my In-App Purchases screen looks like *when you haven't selected the StoreKit configuration*. Their screenshot has everything except the button I described above, because that button only shows up when you edit the scheme, etc.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with the way I've programmed this whole IAP thing to work? I've followed several tutorials online, and they all say that you *must* select the StoreKit configuration if you want to see your IAP info appear on the screen. However, this is kind of a major problem for me, because they won't let my app pass until they see the Button, and they won't see the Button until they select the StoreKit configuration. What should I do here? Thanks in advance for all you help!

Comment: StoreKit configuration file is only for testing of IAPs, especially on simulators. In order to use IAPs in TestFlight or App Store builds, you need to configure them in App Store Connect and submit them along with your app's new build.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev Thank you for your help! Is this an issue that I need to fix in AppStore Connect, or do I need to change my actual code?

Comment: There's not enough code in the question to determine whether you need to change it, but if it works with the StoreKit configuration file, it will likely work without it once you set up the IAP products in App Store Connect. So set up the IAPs, install a TestFlight build on a device and check if it works.